# Issues with validating fields in constructor of a subclass

Tags: java, validation, inheritance, constructor

I am now learning about Java's inheritance. I have total of 3 questions, and thank you for your support.

1st question: Can I validate a class's fields in its constructor?

2nd question: Some people recommended me to throw an exception for validation. Does it mean throwing an exception to the caller method or throwing an exception and handling it inside the constructor?

3rd question: Assuming that the class is not a subclass, can I validate fields as it shows in the code , instead of using exception?(Assuming that the code doesn't create error because of super()).

subclass

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Essay extends GradedActivity
{
   private final double MAXGRAMMAR = 30; 
   private final double MAXSPELLING = 20;   
   private final double MAXLENGTH = 20;
   private final double MAXCONTENT = 30;   

   private double grammar;
   private double spelling;
   private double length;
   private double content;


public Essay(double grammar, double spelling, double length, double content)

  {
      double total;

  while(grammar < 0 || grammar > MAXGRAMMAR)
  {
     grammar = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid grammar value, try again: "));
     this.grammar = grammar;
  }
  while(spelling < 0 || spelling > MAXSPELLING)
  {
     spelling = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid spelling value, try again: "));       
     this.spelling = spelling;
  }
  while(length < 0 || length > MAXLENGTH)
  {
     length = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid length value, try again: "));      
     this.length = length;

  }
  while(content < 0 || content > MAXCONTENT)
  {
     content = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid content value, try again: "));      
     this.content = content;
  }

  total = grammar + spelling + length + content;
  super(total);               
   }
};
```

superclass

```
/**
   A class that holds a grade for a graded activity.
*/

public class GradedActivity
{
   private double score;  // Numeric score

   /**
      The setScore method sets the score field.
      @param s The value to store in score.
   */

   public void setScore(double s)
   {
      score = s;
   }

   /**
      The getScore method returns the score.
      @return The value stored in the score field.
   */

   public double getScore()
   {
      return score;
   }

   /**
      The getGrade method returns a letter grade
      determined from the score field.
      @return The letter grade.
   */

   public char getGrade()
   {
      char letterGrade;

      if (score >= 90)
         letterGrade = 'A';
      else if (score >= 80)
         letterGrade = 'B';
      else if (score >= 70)
         letterGrade = 'C';
      else if (score >= 60)
         letterGrade = 'D';
      else
         letterGrade = 'F';

      return letterGrade;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can have validations in your constructor.
2. There are 2 things you can do here. Either don't let the user create the object with invalid values by throwing the exception and let the caller handle the exception or you define a default when a wrong input is provided. The second option might work in some of the cases. Throwing the exception and handling it right there does not make much of a sense, it's almost like checking the condition and handling it in the else block.
3. There is nothing stopping you from doing what you are doing in the code but as a good coding practice, user input is part of a view, you create a view which allows you to enter required values and do validation on the form and once all the fields are valid, pass it to the constructor. This way the constructor will not have one-off input dialogs for every invalid entry, just the annoyance factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all you are asking, but it is not a good advice to do it.

If you want your code to be maintainable, reusable, extensible and that you can easily implement it in other technologies. Keep the basic concepts of a class with "High cohesion and Low coupling".

A class is just a simple object (Pojo). Keep your constructor clean:

```
Public Essay (Type value){
    this.value=value;
}
```

Leave your Gets and Sets by defaults.

Now, when you have to create these pojos, perform the checks prior to the creation of the object.

You always have a class who create the Pojo (Object) Normaly the constructor:

```
if(validations(fields))
      Abstract class = new ConcreteClass(fields);
else throw new ServiceException("Your exception");
```

So your Answere will be:

1st question: Can I validate a class's fields in its constructor?

> Yes, but it is not recomended to add logic in the constructor.

2nd question: Some people recommended me to throw an exception for validation. Does it mean throwing an exception to the caller method or throwing an exception and handling it inside the constructor?

> The exceptions should be always managed, keep it on a controlate
>   enviroment with propers messages, normaly you create a custome
>   exception for that matter:

```
public class ServiceException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ServiceException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

3rd question: Assuming that the class is not a subclass, can I validate fields as it shows in the code , instead of using exception?(Assuming that the code doesn't create error because of super()).

> If you dont want to validate the fileds before creating the Object, you could do it after with a custom method like -> ConcreteClass.validateFields()

Add to your custome method (validateFields()) the validations that you have now on your constructor and you will get your result.

Hope this helps.